# SwiftUI automatically sizing bottom sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, geometryreader

There are a lot of examples of bottom sheet out there for SwiftUI, however they all specify some type of maximum height the sheet can grow to using a GeometryReader. What I would like is to create a bottom sheet that becomes only as tall as the content within it. I've come up with the solution below using preference keys, but there must be a better solution. Perhaps using some type of dynamic scrollView is the solution?

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var size: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment:.bottom){
            VStack{
                Button(offset == 0 ? "Hide" : "Show"){
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.2)){
                        if offset == 0{
                            offset = size.height
                        } else {
                            offset = 0
                        }
                    }
                }
                .animation(nil)
                .padding()
                .font(.largeTitle)
                Spacer()
            }
            BottomView(offset: $offset, size: $size)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct BottomView: View{
    @Binding var offset: CGFloat
    @Binding var size: CGSize

    var body: some View{
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(0..<5){ value in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(value.isMultiple(of: 2) ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                    .frame(height: 100)
            }
        }
        .offset(x: 0, y: offset)
        .getSize{
            size = $0
            offset = $0.height
        }
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    struct SizePreferenceData {
        let bounds: Anchor<CGRect>
    }

    static var defaultValue: [SizePreferenceData] = []

    static func reduce(value: inout [SizePreferenceData], nextValue: () -> [SizePreferenceData]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct SizePreferenceModifier: ViewModifier {
    let onAppear: (CGSize)->Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .anchorPreference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds, transform: { [SizePreferenceKey.SizePreferenceData( bounds: $0)] })
            .backgroundPreferenceValue(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear{
                            let size = CGSize(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                            onAppear(size)
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View{
    func getSize(_ onAppear: @escaping (CGSize)->Void) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(SizePreferenceModifier(onAppear: onAppear))
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm now using [this](https://fivestars.blog/swiftui/swiftui-share-layout-information.html) approach, which is a little cleaner but it still uses preference keys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Talk about over engineering the problem. All you have to do is specify a height of 0 if you want the sheet to be hidden, and not specify a height when it's shown. Additionally set the frame alignment to be top.

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State private var hide = false

    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
            Color.blue
                .overlay(
                    Text("Is hidden : \(hide.description)").foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.bottom, 200)
                )
                .onTapGesture{
                    hide.toggle()
                }
            
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                ForEach(0..<5){ index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(index.isMultiple(of: 2) ? Color.gray : .orange)
                        .frame(height: 50)
                        .layoutPriority(2)
                }
            }
            .layoutPriority(1)
            .frame(height: hide ? 0 : nil, alignment: .top)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2))
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach is SwiftUI Sheet based solution feel free to check the [gist](https://gist.github.com/bessem/9d012d48dc20a672bc75b80a43fcd29b)

you just need to add the modifier to the view and let iOS do the rest for you, no need to re-do the math ;)
Plus you will have the sheet native behavior (swipe to dismiss) and i added "tap elsewhere" to dismiss.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var activeSheet: Bool = false
@State var activeBottomSheet: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 16){
                Button {
                    activeSheet.toggle()
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Activate Normal sheet")
                            .padding()
                    }.background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    )
                }

                Button {
                    activeBottomSheet.toggle()
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Activate Bottom sheet")
                            .padding()
                    }.background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                            .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    )
                }
            }
    .sheet(isPresented: $activeSheet) {
        // Regular sheet
        sheetView
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $activeBottomSheet) {
        // Responsive sheet
        sheetView
            .asResponsiveSheet()
    }
}

var sheetView: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0){
        ForEach(0..<5){ index in
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(index.isMultiple(of: 2) ? Color.gray : .orange)
                .frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

iPhone:
[image]
iPad :
[image]